# How to extract a value from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an variable which contains this value

```
<AirportCode>LKO</AirportCode> <CityOrAirportName>LUCKNOW AMAUSI</CityOrAirportName> <Country>India</Country> <CountryAbbrviation>IN</CountryAbbrviation> <CountryCode>733</CountryCode> <GMTOffset>-5.5</GMTOffset> <RunwayLengthFeet>7835</RunwayLengthFeet>
```

How can I extract the country code from this, in this case 733. Country code can be different, so I need to somehow get the value which is inside the CountryCode tag

Comment: People might not agree, but using a regular expression might be OK in a simple case like this?

Comment: @Robin That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `div` programmatically. Populate its `innerHTML` and then get `CountryCode` element.

```js
var data = "<AirportCode>LKO</AirportCode> <CityOrAirportName>LUCKNOW AMAUSI</CityOrAirportName> <Country>India</Country> <CountryAbbrviation>IN</CountryAbbrviation> <CountryCode>733</CountryCode> <GMTOffset>-5.5</GMTOffset> <RunwayLengthFeet>7835</RunwayLengthFeet>";

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = data;
console.log(div.querySelector('CountryCode').textContent);
```

Better [parse XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) using

```js
var data = "<AirportCode>LKO</AirportCode> <CityOrAirportName>LUCKNOW AMAUSI</CityOrAirportName> <Country>India</Country> <CountryAbbrviation>IN</CountryAbbrviation> <CountryCode>733</CountryCode> <GMTOffset>-5.5</GMTOffset> <RunwayLengthFeet>7835</RunwayLengthFeet>";

var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString('<root>' + data + '</root>', "text/xml");
console.log(oDOM.querySelector('CountryCode').textContent)
```

Comment: If you're going to parse XML, it's better to parse XML, rather than abusing the HTML parser. (And we don't know this code is running on a browser.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML parsing library, or just a simple RegExp if this is the only thing you want.

Just use the regex: `/<CountryCode>(\d+)<\/CountryCode)/`

For example:

```
var str = '<AirportCode>LKO</AirportCode> <CityOrAirportName>LUCKNOW AMAUSI</CityOrAirportName> <Country>India</Country> <CountryAbbrviation>IN</CountryAbbrviation> <CountryCode>733</CountryCode> <GMTOffset>-5.5</GMTOffset> <RunwayLengthFeet>7835</RunwayLengthFeet>';

function extractCountryCode(xmlStr) {
    var matches = xmlStr.match(/<CountryCode>(\d+)<\/CountryCode)/);
    if (matches.length == 2) {
        return matches[1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

console.log(extractCountryCode(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions indexOf and substring:

(Snippet added to show the result)

```js
var data = "<AirportCode>LKO</AirportCode> <CityOrAirportName>LUCKNOW AMAUSI</CityOrAirportName> <Country>India</Country> <CountryAbbrviation>IN</CountryAbbrviation> <CountryCode>733</CountryCode> <GMTOffset>-5.5</GMTOffset> <RunwayLengthFeet>7835</RunwayLengthFeet>";
    
    var index1 = data.indexOf("<CountryCode>") + "<CountryCode>".length;
    var index2 = data.indexOf("</CountryCode>");

    var code = data.substring(index1, index2);

console.log(code);
```

The addition of CountryCode.length is because the method indexOf will return the first occurrence of the text.

Hope this help.